# how to increment and decrement date in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have to create a app which displays current date. On forward swiping date should be incremented and on backward swiping date should be decremented.

I am succeeded in displaying current date and increment on swiping forward. But I don't how to decrement on swiping backward in single activity.

Here is my code.

**TAB activity**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,position);
        String dte = sdf.format(c.getTime()).toString();
        TextView textView2 =  getView().findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView2.setText(dte);
    }
}
```

Comment: If I were to build this app then I would have used any GitHub date picker library for android. Or make use of this [Pickers, read google developers documentation for pickers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
int daysToDecrement = -1;
c.add(Calendar.DATE, daysToDecrement);
```

this will decrement date by one.
So based on your backwardswipe you have to decrement the number of days.

Answer (score 0):

just u need to change your mode to spinner in layout Date picker for increment and detriment,

`android:datePickerMode="spinner"`

Answer (score 0):

Use `Calendar.DATE` instead of `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` and pass position that how many days you want to increase or decrease. For example increase two day use `2` and for decrease two day use `-2`.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.DATE, position);
String dte = sdf.format(c.getTime()).toString();
```